# How do i get an Target on an location herf if its in an onclick event

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, onclick

We are programming an Webside in school (10th grade). So i were setting up my Menue at the top of my page and i ran into a problem. I got a "Table" to set everything up and inside there i got Hyperlinks to my other pages. I wanted that if i press the cube around the Hyperlink it goes to the other pag. So i settet up an "onclick=location.href" in my "td". The problem with that is i cannot add anymore an "Target" attribute to the herf. So my Question is how can i set an Target Attribute to this "onclick=location.href". We arent allowd to use JavaScript. We are just allowed to use html and css. Thanks for evry answers <3. Merry Chrismas to all btw.

```
<table class="menue">
            <tr>
            
                    <td style="cursor:pointer" onclick="location.href='../../../home.html'">        <a href="../../../home.html"        target="_top">  Home        </a></td>
                    <td style="cursor:pointer" onclick="location.href='../../../ueber_mich.html'">  <a href="../../../ueber_mich.html"  target="_top">  Über mich   </a></td>
                    <td class="menuereiter"> Auch hier unterwegs </td>
                    <td style="cursor:pointer" onclick="location.href='../../../skills.html'">      <a href="../../../skills.html"      target="_top">  Skills      </a></td>
                    <td style="cursor:pointer" onclick="location.href='../../../gear.html'">        <a href="../../../gear.html"        target="_top">  Gear        </a></td>
            
            </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: why are you using onclick than if you are not allowed  to use javascript ??

Comment: We arent allowed to use Js files cuz our school Computers cant Handel it if we open one. (PC crashes) and the onclick is there to get me to another Website and Not to run an JS file.

Comment: you dont have to use on click just use a tag and target="_blank" thats wht u need check the snnipet.if this helps you tahn dont forget to upvote it thanks

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table class="menue">
            <tr>
            
                    <td > <a href="../../../home.html"        target="_blank" style="cursor:pointer">  Home  </a></td>
               <td> <a href="../../../ueber_mich.html" target="_blank" style="cursor:pointer"> Über mich </a></td>
                    <td class="menuereiter"> Auch hier unterwegs </td>
                       <td > <a href="../../../skills.html"        target="_blank" style="cursor:pointer">  Skills  </a></td>
               <td> <a href="../../../gear.html" target="_blank" style="cursor:pointer"> Gear </a></td>
                    <td class="menuereiter"> Auch hier unterwegs </td>
    
            </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: _blank Opens the linked document in a new window or tab and _top Opens the linked document in the full body of the window

Comment: This is not the solution for the thing i asked. If u look at my code at the top u see that the hyperlink got an target="_top". I tryed to get an hyperlink an my tablecell so i did an onclick an the "td" and on the onclick the hyperlink but i need an target="_top" on it and not just on the written Text. So i got an Table with text and i want if the table cell is pressed that i get 2 an other webside. (This is an menue btw)
Best regards